# WSO2 MB Cluster Giving Connection reset by peer

Tags: wso2, wso2-message-broker

Test cluster of two brokers, WKA membership scheme, PostgreSQL message store, working fine for a couple of days, then throwing following errors:

```
TID: [] [] [2016-07-19 12:09:24,738] ERROR {org.wso2.andes.server.protocol.MultiVersionProtocolEngine} -  Error establishing session {org.wso2.andes.server.protocol.MultiVersionProtocolEngine}
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
    at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketIoProcessor.read(SocketIoProcessor.java:218)
    at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketIoProcessor.process(SocketIoProcessor.java:198)
    at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketIoProcessor.access$400(SocketIoProcessor.java:45)
    at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketIoProcessor$Worker.run(SocketIoProcessor.java:485)
    at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:51)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Startup of Message Broker looks fine, no errors, JDBC connection to PostgreSQL DB is ok, Registry mount looks ok. Then after that error appears in wso2carbon.log several times/minute. 
Anyone any ideas? As far as I know nothing's changed and I don't know what it's trying to connect to.

Comment: WSO2 MB 3.1 cluster.

Comment: Hi TanyaK can you explain the usecase that is run against this MB cluster. Are you using queues or topics. Is this occurring in a long running test? What is the TPS?

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when client's whom connected to MB tries to create connections per message. jms is heavy connection and not recommended to create connections per each message. Therefore, please go through client implementation and verify connections are not created per message.

If by any chance you are using wso2 esb to publish/subscribe queues/topics to mb there is a property "transport.jms.CacheLevel" [connection caching](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/JMS+Transport) in esb axis2.xml.Read the [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/JMS+Transport) and use appropriate caching level for your usecase.

There was [bug](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-3607) in connection caching property to be ignored in esb 4.8.1 which is currently fixed in 4.9.0 as well.
These are the possible cases I can think of with the given information. If you need more info please provide a detailed usecase.